# Unable to add_filter in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am adding a filter in wordpress plugin.
Filter:

```
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'saveuser_filter');
```

And calling it in `functions.php` file with below code:

```
function saveuser_filter($use_number, $use_code){
    $use_num = $use_number;
    $use = $use_code;
    global $wpdb;
    $mydb = new wpdb('username','password','database','host');
    $stmt1 = $mydb->query("INSERT INTO wpconfig (use_num, use) VALUES ('$use_num', '$use')");
    $resu = $mydb->query($mydb->prepare($stmt1));
     if($resu)
     {
         $resu="Data Inserted Successfully:";
         echo json_encode($resu);
     }
     else {
         $error="Not Inserted,Some Probelm occur.";
         echo json_encode($error);
     }
}
```

However, I am saving these details after user completes an order on woocommerce. But anyhow, its giving error: `Unable to create order.` and order is not getting placed. Please suggest what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: probably you should return, not echo data. Look [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_insert_post_data)

Comment: Thanks but could using `echo` create errors?

Comment: I think the filter should return something and here is the problem. echo does not create errors, but the fact that the function returns nothing can cause problems. Therefore, I suggest that you try to replace the code with a `return json_encode ($ resu);`

Comment: Hope it will work :)

Comment: Still no luck. Got same error again.

Comment: When using a filter hooked function, you always need to return the first argument which is `$use_number`… A filter hook is made to alter the data that pass though, but not to do what you are doing actually that should be done in an action hook.